# Which tools\techniques are you using to improve performance of mass deletion of custom object records?

Tags: data-loader, bulk-api, delete

We have a custom object with about 40 million records. We have identified about 18 million that we are going to delete forever.  All of this data is permanently retained in an Oracle backup so we are happy to go with Hard Delete via Bulk API.  However, this technique (via Data Loader) results in a slew of errors (such as "Unable to obtain exclusive access to this record") and no noticeable improvement in speed.  Outside of this experience we have never had good luck with Bulk API, largely due to this nagging "exclusive access" error.

Using a standard delete in Data Loader we are experiencing just over 8000 deletions a minute.  Switching to Informatica Cloud (again without using Bulk API) we get approximately the same rate).

Are there any other tricks\tips\techniques that we should look at to improve speed?

Comment: It'll probably take longer to get another workable solution in place than it would to just sit and wait for Data Loader to do its thing. With your given numbers, it should take around 37.5 hours to complete. Why not just set it to work over the weekend?

Comment: If possible, disabling all triggers, war, etc prior to the delete would speed things up: http://sftoolkit.co - Of course you may want to disable login access before doing so to prevent data skew. You could test it out at least to see the speed of record deletion with all the stuff turned off

Comment: The ultimate way to speed up is to do it same night as release (or any other time where all users are logged out by force) and disable all related triggers/workflows. If that option is available, speed will dramatically increase.